# Is this sentence an example of parataxis?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, phrases, sentence

I'm writing a paper and want to be certain I am understanding this concept correctly. Is this sentence an example of parataxis?

> You had to live — did live, from habit that became instinct — in the assumption that every sound you made was overheard, and, except in darkness, every movement scrutinized.

Source: George Orwell, *1984*

Comment: Looks more like a parenthetical expression, as the second portion directly corrects the first part.

Comment: an expression can be parenthetical without the use of parenthesis ? ahh i know less than i thought, haha

Comment: It's certainly not parataxis as I understand the term. It is constructed deftly and builds to a logical outcome, with the various parts serving the whole. Parataxis is just a lot of parts that eventually ask the listener to sum them up.

Comment: If you're trying to find examples of parataxis, I think James Joyce would offer more fertile territory than George Orwell! (Or just about any modern sports commentator! :)